# gdb disassemble by line number

Tags: c, gdb

Say I want to disassemble lines m-n of file x, where file x is not in the current context. Is this operation possible, and if so, how? Note: I am working on x86 Linux.

Comment: I'm sure it depends on the optimization flags, and you'll only really be able to do this at `-O0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a kludgy way to do it: set a breakpoint on the line you're interested in, and the breakpoint acknowledgement gives you an address. Then clear the breakpoint and run `disas` or `x/20i` on that address.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the disassemble command with the `/m` key to display original C lines in front of their assembly counterparts:

```
disassemble /m 'my_file.c'::my_function
```

This does not require any preliminary steps, although it doesn't seem to accept source line ranges as you asked.

Answer (score 3):

As a quite late and maybe redundant answer, but hopefully useful for someone like me, I would like to put together a complete response to this and [your other question on getting the address of a line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287188/gdb-find-memory-address-of-line-number/11287482).

The `disassemble` command [can disassemble address ranges](http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/disassemble): `disassemble [Start],[End]`. But you want to disassemble line ranges.

To get the addresses of the source code lines you can use [the `info line` command](http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/info_line): `info line [File]:[Line]`.