# gdb find memory address of line number

Tags: c, linux, gdb, x86

Say I have attached gdb to a process and within the its memory layout there is a file and line number which I would like the memory address of. How can I get the memory address of line n in file x? This is on Linux x86.

Comment: More or less a duplicate of [gdb disassemble by line number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285932/gdb-disassemble-by-line-number) - the answer to that question is a perfectly good answer to this one as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
(gdb) info line test.c:56
Line 56 of "test.c" starts at address 0x4005ae <main+37>
   and ends at 0x4005ba <main+49>.
```

additionally with python you may be able to use the 'last' attribute from
[Symbol-Tables-In-Python](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbol-Tables-In-Python.html#Symbol-Tables-In-Python) this currently requires a very recent version of gdb from cvs, but i imagine will have general availability in 7.5

```
(gdb) py x = gdb.find_pc_line(gdb.decode_line("test.c:56")[1][0].pc); gdb.execute("p/x " + str(x.pc)); gdb.execute("p/x " + str(x.last))
$15 = 0x4005ae
$16 = 0x4005b9
```

Comment: info line! That's what we needed on that other question.